# Server Post URL variable issue

Tags: php, wordpress, server-side

This is my site http://www.elitelifestylesgroup.com/
This is build on WordPress template. The template is using Visual builder which is drag and drop. 
I have an image as call to action button. There is only 3 ways I can assign a link to that image.
1. light box
2. set manually (accept url)
3. set to page

however this is what I want. I have inserted this code on the Theme folder the server inside index.php

```
 <?php 

/*   On page 1: Copy this to your Index.php inside Theme */

$ownid="sponsor=873811769";

if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != ""))
{
    $url = "https://multibuyworld.eu/?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
else 
{
    $url = "https://multibuyworld.eu/?".$ownid;
}

session_register();
session_start();                     
$_SESSION['url'] = $url; 
?>
```

Then I have created another php file called singupm.php with this code inside. 
both file is inside the theme folder directory

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $page = $_COOKIE['url'];

    header('Location: '.$page);
?>
```

On the image which act as call to action button I use this url "http://elitelifestylesgroup.com/wp-content/themes/enfold/singupm.php"

This should redirect to exernal url but it does not.

but it just open this url as blank page where the singup.php is. (does not allow me more than two link)

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with $page = $_COOKIE['url'];
I believe it should be $_SESSION['url']; since you're using a session to store the variable.

Comment: I did use $_SESSION['url'] but the same results. I had that initialy

Comment: Maybe instead of having two php files, and using a session, you could put header('Location: '.$url); at the end of the first file.

Comment: That is how i did it initially, something weird, this exact code works with html website, maybe it has to do with the wrodpress template

Comment: maybe, header won't work if there is any html code above it in the file, is that the problem?

Comment: you could take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/turn-on-wordpress-error-reporting/ to enable error reporting, hopefully it'll print an error that reveals the issue